# How to get all parameter's value from given URL?

Tags: php

I have one URL string like

```
'http://example.com/glamour/url.php?ad_id=[ad_id]&pubid=[pubid]&click_id=[click_id]'
```

So I want to fetch value of all parameters which mentioned in [].
Like ad_id,pubid,clickid

How can I fetch values of parameters?

Comment: I use: print_r($_GET);

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   echo $_GET['ad_id']; // ad_id is the name of parameter.
?>
```

This code will give you the value of parameter

For String of URL try this :

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['ad_id'];
```

Comment: I have string of URL. So I can not use this. I want to fetch it from string of URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this command.

```
 print_r($_GET);
```

And then you could see the all parameters in the url.

Comment: I have string of URL. So I can not use this. I want to fetch it from string of URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code to get all parts of query:

```
<?php
    /* Parse url */
    $url = 'http://example.com/url.php?ad_id=[ad_id]&pubid=[pubid]';
    parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $query_data );

    /* Results */
    var_dump($query_data['ad_id']);
    var_dump($query_data['pubid']);
?>
```